# redirects issue in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Recently I configured my website for https and redirected http to https but now in google page speed, I am getting issue of Too many redirects!

Can be checked at: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=peterkentconsulting.com&tab=desktop

[image: google snapshot]
And Google explains: Your page has 2 redirects, site is wordpress multisite. Please help me to remove those redirects..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by editing site url at wp_site and wp_options tables in database.

Comment: thanks @WorddssInfotech - that solved an issue of mine after I cloned some WP sites as they were pointing to the wrong site urls

Answer (score 1):

Your http to https redirect is not working fine. You should configure all urls:

```
http://peterkentconsulting.com/ 
http://www.peterkentconsulting.com/
http://www.peterkentconsulting.com/index.php
```

to

```
https://www.peterkentconsulting.com/
```

Now as I see your site's all requests are first going to `/index.php` which wordpress redirects to `/` in its *.htaccess*.

You should directly redirect `http://www.peterkentconsulting.com/` to `https://www.peterkentconsulting.com/`